Does a $\rm Spin^c$ connection reduce to an $\rm U(1)$ connection when there is a spin structure?
In the physics literature, it has been used the concept of Spin$^c$ structure (see for example 1) for the description of fermions in condensed matter systems (where fermions have odd U(1) charges). It is usually described in terms of a Spin$^c$ connection $A$, which is locally the same as an U(1) connection but with a modified flux quantization
\begin{equation}
\int_C \frac{F}{2\pi} + \frac{1}{2} w_2 \in \mathbb{Z},
\end{equation}
where $C$ is some 2-cycle, $F$ is the curvature of $A$ and $w_2= w_2(TX)$ is the second Stiefel-Whitney class ($X$ is our manifold of dimensiond $d$). This twisted flux condition basically ensures that I can define consistently spinors with odd U(1) charge (i.e. in an irrep of U(1) defined by an odd integer) even when $w_2 \neq 0$ in cohomology.
When $X$ admits a spin structure, thus $w_2$ is exact, $w_2 = d \eta$ mod 2, then the above flux quantization reduces to the standard one for an U(1) connection (since $\int_C d\eta =0$). Does this mean that when $X$ admits a spin structure there is no difference between a Spin$^c$ connection and a U(1) connection?
